# How to add the environment name in the app name with Cordova for Windows dynamically?

Tags: cordova, windows-10, win-universal-app

I want to add "Test" in the app name when I release with Cordova :

```
cordova prepare -mode=test
```

When I release with Cordova for other OS it is ok but for Windows 10 it only change in :
platforms\windows\package.windows10.appxmanifest

the value :

```
  <Properties><DisplayName>MyApp Test</DisplayName></Properties>
```

but the real name of the app on Windows file system and on the bar title is managed by the value :

```
<Applications>
    <Application Id="myid" StartPage="xxx/index.html">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="**value here**">
```

I can do this manually but that would be problematic to add this step for each release and I would like to be able to generate it automatically.

My goal is :

- to display clearly if we are in prod or test.
- to be able to install both app (test and prod) on the same computer, it would be possible if they don't have the same name.
- to automate this (no manual change).

I use :
Cordova 10 and Windows 10 universal Windows project released with VS 2017.